# How to ask storage permission on android 11,10 and older version with same code?

Tags: java, android

I have created an android app and its working fine in my mobile (Android v5) and in some mobile (android 11) it doesn't fetch data from download folder and when I tested in client phone (Android 10) it fetches data from download folder and show in recycle view but when we click on item it crashes but if the problem in in adapter class why it is not crashing in android 5?

**I am using easy permission library for storage permission**

```
String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
            // Already have permission, do the thing
            // ...
            if(interstitialAd.isAdLoaded()){
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
            downloadFile(DownloadActivity.this,imageList.get(selectedPosition),displayPosition);

        } else {
            // Do not have permissions, request them now
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Please Grant Storage Permissions !",101, perms);
        }
```

**This is the manifest file code**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.KineMasterProject">
        <activity android:name=".ImportActivity"></activity>
```

**Apk File link**

```
http://www.filehost.pt/2Muig
```

Comment: Please post the crash logs. There is logcat tab at the bottom of Android Studio. When it crashed, check the logchat and update your post with it

Comment: Perhaps this is a better question for the `EasyPermissions` author.

Comment: Actually App is running on my phone (Android 5) Perfectly but it crashes as I said before in Client Phone (Android 10 ) So how can I use logcat to check error. He is from different country.